# Bootstrap tooltip not triggering automatic when codeigniter form error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

On my codeigniter project When I submit form if there is a error it should show the bootstrap tool tip automatic.

But for some reason I have to keep on clicking on the input to show bootstrap tool tip

Question: When I have a form error how to make sure it shows that tool tip with out me clicking on any thing?

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php if ($error_title != '') {?>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=title]').tooltip({
        placement: "right",
        title: '<?php echo $error_title;?>',
        trigger: "focus"
    });
});
<?php }?>
</script>
```

Full View

````
<?php echo $header;?><?php echo $navbar;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('questions/ask', array('id' => 'form-ask'));?>

<div class="container">
<div class="row medium-spacer">
<div class="col-sm-8">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="title_label" for="title">Title: </label>
<span class="title_input">
<?php 

$title_array = array(
    'name' => 'title',
    'value' => $title,
    'id' => 'input-title',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
);

echo form_input($title_array);?>

</span>
</div>

<div class="panel ask panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="#ask" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ask Question</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#preview" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Preview</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="ask">
    <div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_textarea('message', '', array('id' => 'message', 'class' => 'form-control'));?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="preview">
        <div class="preview-message"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<?php echo form_submit('ask', 'Post Your Question', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'));?>
</div>

</div>



<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="well">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li>For blocks of code, to preserve newlines, use one of the following methods:</li><br/>
<li>
<ul>
    <li>Single Line Backtick Escapes<code>`Example`</code></li>
    <li>Indent everything four (4) spaces or</li>
    <li>(3) Backticks start and end of code<br/><br/>
<pre>
```
&lt;div class="form-group"&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
```
</pre>
</li>

</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<?php echo form_close();?>

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php if ($error_title != '') {?>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=title]').tooltip({
        placement: "right",
        title: '<?php echo $error_title;?>',
        trigger: "focus"
    });
});
<?php }?>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("a[data-target=\'#preview\']").on('click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>question/ask/preview',
            type: "post",
            data: {'message': $('#message').val()},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(json){ 
                $('.preview-message').html(json['preview']);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
</script>

<?php echo $footer;?>
````

Comment: Try removing trigger: "focus"

Comment: @Yolo nothing happend

Comment: See my answer please

Answer (score 1):

## solution

Using `.tooltip('show');` at end

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name=title]').tooltip({
        placement: "right",
        container:'body',
        title: '<?php echo $error_title;?>',
        /*trigger: "hover"*/
    }).tooltip('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('[title]').tooltip({
      position: {my: "left top", at: "left bottom"}
    }).tooltip('open');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  

Title <input name="title" title="Im a tooltip!">
```